# How can I replace multiple Strings with str_replace?

Tags: php, joomla, str-replace

How can I replace multiple strings with `str_replace`?

```
$oldurl = JFactory::getURI();
$newurl = str_replace('example1', 'replacedwiththis', $oldurl);
```

but I need that this code works also if the `URL` contains `example2`.
So I need a code that changes both `example1` and `example2` with `replacedwiththis`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `str_replace()` you can define an array of 'needles' to find (http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

So you can do ...

```
$newurl = str_replace(['example1','example2'], 'replacedwiththis', $oldurl);
```